# htaccess prevent accessig user accounts using /~

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've received an email from Google saying my site contains phishing contents. When I checked the URL they sent, it was just a URL accessing another hosting account via my domain.

```
Ex: domain.com/~username
```

Is there a way to prevent this from either using .htaccess file or any other method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the disable the use of the feature you are describing (better known as `UserDir`) you could specify the following in either your `httpd.conf` or within your *vhost configuration*.

There is no way to change this setting from within `.htaccess`.

```
UserDir disabled
```

---

#### Read more about it by following the below link:

- **[httpd.apache.org - Per-user web directories - Enable/Disable](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/public_html.html#enable)**
- **[httpd.apache.org - Apache Module mod_userdir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_userdir.html#userdir)**

Comment: Just FYI, this setting can only be changed in `httpd.conf` or within a vhost configuration, not `.htaccess`.  OP can also disable it completely by commenting the line `LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so` in `httpd.conf`.